# Change number format for add_table worksheet writer in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I want to adjust my numbers format in my excel table from `1000,12` to the European style (with thousand separator): `1.000,12` with python.

In excel the format is set-up with: `#.##0,00`

When I want to use it in my workbook with `xlsxwriter` (flattened is a dataframe table):

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('excel.xlsx', options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True})
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('table1')
numbersformat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#.##0,00'})
worksheet1.add_table(3, 1, flattened.shape[0]+3, flattened.shape[1],
    {'data': flattened.values.tolist(),
    'columns': [{'header': c} for c in flattened.columns.tolist()],
    'style': 'Table Style Medium 9',
    'format': numbersformat})
```

I get an empty dataframe. Whereever leads to the outcome of the table:

```
worksheet1.add_table(3, 1, flattened.shape[0]+3, flattened.shape[1],
    {'data': flattened.values.tolist(),
    'columns': [{'header': c} for c in flattened.columns.tolist()],
    'style': 'Table Style Medium 9',})
```

My dataframe `flattened` looks like this:

```
Department Name Month:1 Month:2 Month:All
Bistro     Ama  82.75            82.75
Bistro     Beb  100.00  212.00   312.00
All             182.75  212.00    394.75
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to adjust my numbers format in my excel table from 1000,12 to the European style (with thousand separator): 1.000,12 with python.
>
> In excel the format is set-up with: `#.##0,00`

The issue here is that even though the format is displayed as `#.##0,00` it is actually stored by Excel as `#,##0.00` (i.e., US locale). Your OS probably has a default thousands separator of "." and decimal separator of "," and Excel changes `#,##0.00` to `#.##0,00` when it reads and displays the values.

Your program should work as expected if you change the code to have the US style format:

```py
numbersformat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
```

**Update:**

You are also adding the format in the wrong place. It is a property of the column not the whole table. Here is a working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

flattened = pd.DataFrame({'Department': ['Bistro', 'Bistro', 'All'],
                          'Name':       ['Ama',    'Beb',    None],
                          'Month:1':    [182.75,    1100.00, 1182.75],
                          'Month:2':    ['',        1212.00, 1212.00],
                          'Month:All':  [182.75,    2312.00, 2394.75]})

# Set the dataframe column order.
flattened = flattened[['Department', 'Name',  'Month:1',
                       'Month:2', 'Month:All']]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('excel.xlsx',
                               options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True})

worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('table1')

# Make the columns wider for clarity.
worksheet1.set_column(1, flattened.shape[1], 11)

numbersformat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})

worksheet1.add_table(3, 1, flattened.shape[0]+3, flattened.shape[1],
    {'data': flattened.values.tolist(),
     'columns': [{'header': c, 'format': numbersformat}
                 for c in flattened.columns.tolist()],
     'style': 'Table Style Medium 9'})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

And here is the same file when the Windows or macOS regional settings have "," as the decimal separator and "." as the thousands separator:

[image]

The difference is explained in the XlsxWriter docs: [Number Formats in different locales](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-formats-in-different-locales).

Comment: still blank table, i think I am adding the format as the wrong part of the code...

Comment: Can you update your code to make it a full working example with a sample data frame and “flattened”.

Comment: It helps a bit but a full working example, like mine, would have helped more. Also, you are correct that you are adding the format in the wrong place. See my updates.